# PHP Google Calendar API - Updating an event

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

It's a newbie question, I'm not used to the Google API yet

---

Hi,

I'm using the code provided by Google ( https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/downloads )  that are coming with some examples (originally because it seemed more up-to-date).

I am successfully retrieving the calendars as the example "calendar/simple.php" shows (OAuth2 setup is correct).

**After that, I'm doing this and it works (it's a non necessary code, just for checking if the event can be retrieved properly without any error):**

```
$test = $cal->events->get("calendar@gmail.com","longeventcodegivenbygoogle");
```

**Now, I want to be  able to set some values of a specific event.**

```
$event = new Event();
$event->setLocation('Somewhere');
$test = $cal->events->update("calendar@gmail.com","longeventcodegivenbygoogle",$event);
```

**But it's giving me:**

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'apiServiceException' with message 'Error calling PUT https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendar@gmail.com/events/longeventcodegivenbygoogle?key=myapikey: (400) Required' in C:\wamp\www\test\Gapi3\src\io\apiREST.php on line 86
( ! ) apiServiceException: Error calling PUT https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendar@gmail.com/events/longeventcodegivenbygoogle?key=myapikey: (400) Required in C:\wamp\www\test\Gapi3\src\io\apiREST.php on line 86
```

What do I do wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real solution is given by Claudio Cherubino with a call of the event Class to create the event object.

**By default, it seems that the get() does not return an event object but an array.**

```
$event = new Event($cal->events->get("calendar@gmail.com","longeventcodegivenbygoogle"));
$event->setLocation('Somewhere');
$updated = new Event($cal->events->update("calendar@gmail.com", $event->getId(), $event));
```

If you do not create the event with the array supplied by update() or get() it will not work since it's a simple array that is being returned by these calls.

Comment: It seems like you need to use new Google_Event

Answer (score 4):

In order to update an event, you retrieve it first and then change the values of its properties instead of instantiating a new one.

Try the following code:

```
$event = $cal->events->get("calendar@gmail.com","longeventcodegivenbygoogle");
$event->setLocation('Somewhere');
$updated = $cal->events->update("calendar@gmail.com", $event->getId(), $event);
```